# How to extract sequence of rows in output data pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a datetime based dataframe as below,

```
                   timestamp       value  ...         metric        
36 2014-04-02 17:20:00  125.098263  ...           25.098263         
14 2014-04-06 16:25:00  140.072787  ...           265.171050        
10 2014-04-11 09:00:00  127.882020  ...           393.053070        
45 2014-04-11 09:05:00  115.705719  ...           508.758789        
24 2014-04-11 09:15:00  127.261178  ...           636.019967        
17 2014-04-11 09:20:00  121.157997  ...           757.177965        
49 2014-04-11 09:25:00  120.468468  ...           877.646433        
8  2014-04-11 09:45:00  135.642696  ...           1013.289128       
33 2014-04-11 09:55:00  125.210049  ...           1138.499178       
19 2014-04-11 10:05:00  159.259713  ...           1297.758890       
52 2014-04-11 10:20:00  150.082482  ...           1447.841373
```

I want to create new column named as 'diff_col' contains either 'same' or 'diff' values.
If a date is not continuous, it will taken as 'diff' otherwise it is 'same'.
In the above dataframe, 2014-04-02 17:20:00 and  2014-04-06 16:25:00 are different dates compare to remaining datetime values.

How to create the diff_col .

I tried,
df['diff_col']=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'timestamp', freq='1D'))

but it didn't correctly create the expected column.
My required dataframe is as below,

```
         timestamp       value  ...         metric               diff_col
36 2014-04-02 17:20:00  125.098263  ...           25.098263         diff
14 2014-04-06 16:25:00  140.072787  ...           265.171050        diff
10 2014-04-11 09:00:00  127.882020  ...           393.053070        same
45 2014-04-11 09:05:00  115.705719  ...           508.758789        same
24 2014-04-11 09:15:00  127.261178  ...           636.019967        same
17 2014-04-11 09:20:00  121.157997  ...           757.177965        same
49 2014-04-11 09:25:00  120.468468  ...           877.646433        same
8  2014-04-11 09:45:00  135.642696  ...           1013.289128       same
33 2014-04-11 09:55:00  125.210049  ...           1138.499178       same
19 2014-04-11 10:05:00  159.259713  ...           1297.758890       same
52 2014-04-11 10:20:00  150.082482  ...           1447.841373       same
```

Please provide suggestion on this.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the successive rows to see if this is the same date (extracted with [`dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html)) and use this as grouper to get the size with [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), if the size is > 1, set 'same' else 'diff' with help of [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

# ensure datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# get day
s = df['timestamp'].dt.normalize()

# compare successive rows and identify group size
df['diff_col'] = np.where(df.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())
                            .transform('size').gt(1),
                          'same', 'diff')
```

Output:

```
             timestamp       value  ...       metric diff_col
36 2014-04-02 17:20:00  125.098263  ...    25.098263     diff
14 2014-04-06 16:25:00  140.072787  ...   265.171050     diff
10 2014-04-11 09:00:00  127.882020  ...   393.053070     same
45 2014-04-11 09:05:00  115.705719  ...   508.758789     same
24 2014-04-11 09:15:00  127.261178  ...   636.019967     same
17 2014-04-11 09:20:00  121.157997  ...   757.177965     same
49 2014-04-11 09:25:00  120.468468  ...   877.646433     same
8  2014-04-11 09:45:00  135.642696  ...  1013.289128     same
33 2014-04-11 09:55:00  125.210049  ...  1138.499178     same
19 2014-04-11 10:05:00  159.259713  ...  1297.758890     same
52 2014-04-11 10:20:00  150.082482  ...  1447.841373     same
```

Comment: Hi mozway, why you are using 'size' as param for transform here. size means rows*cols. why not only rows.

Comment: @user680288 no, this is not the same as `df.size`, this means here the number of rows, including NaNs

Comment: And anyways, `transform` works on Series, so the data is 1D